# Bluetooth Low-Energy INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a trouble.I want use Bluetooth Low-Energy in my project, I'm select "Open Bluetooth Low-Energy API [Android 2.3.3]" SDK create project.But it's not work. It throws exceptions are as follows:
**Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
Please check logcat output for more details.
Launch canceled!**

such a configuration in my engineering
I want to find a sample can reference,When I find a sample in the “samples\android-10\BluetoothChat\src\com\example\android\BluetoothChat”,
I found that it is not what I need.It is not related with Bluetooth Low-Energy. why haven't Bluetooth Low Energy sample in android SDK?
Who can you give me a sample? or tell me how to do it? 
Please help me, thanks very very much !

Answer (score 0):

Have look on this topic [How to use Broadcom BLE SDK (SMART 4.0) in Android 4.X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11311947/how-to-use-broadcom-ble-sdk-smart-4-0-in-android-4-0)

Android doesn't have a BLE library ready to use. You could try specific [Broadcom](http://code.google.com/p/broadcom-ble/) and Motorola library, but the Bluetooth phone chip must be compatible.

In others words : No BLE support on Android at this time.

Comment: Thank you very much you gave me good advice.But when I use Broadcom still make such a mistake: the Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY Please check logcat output for more details Launch temporarily canceled as! Is my device does not support the cause?

Comment: Acc. to this web site, only some model of the HTC One X and Smasung Galaxy could work with this lib : http://ble.stalliance.no/

Comment: I am using a Galaxy S3 device testing, but still this error appears ：the Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY Please check logcat output for more details Launch temporarily canceled as!
Is it can only be used to the Motorola equipment test this?

Comment: I don't know. As I said, you need to have the right chip embedded in your phone to work with. There is several kind of S3 Galaxy models depending on your localization (US, Europe, ...). I have never heard someone who is able to use BLE on Android.

Comment: Oh, thank you sdespont! I may not know enough about this，Thanks again for your reply to my question.

Comment: Good news, BLE support in 4.2 Android version. To confirm, but here is a Broadcom news http://www.broadcom.com/press/release.php?id=s721534 Please, share with us if you find something interresting

Comment: sorry,busy recently, so now I see your reply message, thank you very much, the weekend i will study if there is good news, i will tell you.thanks for sdespont again!