# Motorola Bluetooth Low Energy API support for tablet

Tags: android, motorola, bluetooth-lowenergy, broadcom

I am looking to find a tablet (preferred) or a phone that supports and has all neccessary drivers for BTLE. The phone or tablet must be running Android OS. I understand that currently android does not have any BTLE functionality in it, but both Broadcomm and Motorola have BTLE API. I need to be able to facilitate a 2 way communication path with a custom device.

My understanding of the Motorola API is that it currently supports only the HRM profile and nothing else for BTLE. If this is true, can this profile meet my needs?

Is there any distinct advantage between the current Android BTLE packages?

Comment: Duplicate, check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041378/bluetooth-smart-4-0-gatt-support-in-android-4-0/13600962#13600962

Answer (score 1):

Motorola ICS_R2 has an example how to communicate with HRM, but there is enough in the API to communicate with any other profile -- as long as the GATT database resides on the "other" device (e.g., HRM). I have the XT885 here, works fine with custom BLE device. The API documentation is poor and misleading, the best is to decompile the BluetoothDevice and BluetoothGattService classes from ICS_R2 and using that for docs.

The distinct advantage of ICS_R2 is that after beating it for few days, I found that it works :-)